# Problem in extracting rows based on common columns with tolerance in terms of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to extract rows by comparing the two dataframes with defined tolerance value.
The column I want to compare is in terms of decimal year (Which I calculated from the available time).
TO get the desired precision in seconds the allowed tolerance is
`dt=1.8973892110807355e-06`.

df1

```
YearDeci                rms
2008.5051149999999    0.22
2008.5051149999999    0.22
2008.5051149999999    0.35
2008.5051149999999    0.39
2008.5051149999999    0.44
2008.5051149999999    0.18
2008.5051149999999    0.26
2008.5051149999999    0.41
2008.5051149999999    0.40
2008.5051149999999    0.37
2008.5051149999999    0.12
2008.5097550000000    0.24
2008.5097550000000    0.18
2008.5253180000000    0.24
2008.5253180000000    0.13
```

df2

```
YearDeci            rms
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5051180000000  0.84
2008.5253200000000  0.74
2008.5253200000000  0.74
2008.5253200000000  0.74
2008.5253200000000  0.74
2008.5379909999999  0.60
```

My code is

```
tmp=np.isclose(df1.YearDeci[:,np.newaxis],df2.YearDeci[np.newaxis,:],atol=dt, rtol=0)
tmp=np.argwhere(tmp)
df_tmp=pd.DataFrame(tmp,columns=['ind1', 'ind2'])
result = df_tmp.merge(df1, left_on='ind1', right_index=True).merge(df2,left_on='ind2', right_index=True, suffixes=['_temp1', '_temp2'])
```

I am expecting a 15-row output (exactly as df1) with 4 columns, But I am getting 118 rows instead, seems like there is repetition.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: any time you merge on a df that has duplicate columns you should expect duplicates in your output

Comment: Can you update your question w/your expected output?

Comment: `pd.merge_asof` might be useful.